# Juice UI droppable example - clueless newbie can't get workage happening

Tags: juice-ui

Sorry, total Juice UI newbie, and really a web app newbie as well.  Having trouble getting the simple example working from the Juice UI website.  It is supposed to illustrate how easy it is to make a drag-drop example, but I get a lot of errors which makes me think I'm missing something really basic. I'm trying to use the Droppable control, documented here:
http://juiceui.com/controls/droppable

The draggable example worked fine, so I've gotten that far, but when I paste the droppable example text into my C# web application, I get errors that the style needs to be outside the form, outside the body, etc - I keep moving it up the chain. Eventually it says "element style needs to be in a parent element" - not sure where to put it if I can't put it on the page.  I suppose in a .css file?  Also, it says the  tag is missing a required attribute 'type'.

Any help would be much appreciated!

```
<style>
    .draggable { width: 100px; height: 100px; padding: 0.5em; float: left; margin: 10px 10px 10px 0; }
    .droppable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; float: left; margin: 10px; }
</style>

<script>
    $(function(){
        $( "#_Default" ).droppable( "option", "drop", function( event, ui ) {
            $( this )
                .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
                .find( "p" )
                    .html( "Dropped!" );
            }
        );
    });
</script>

<asp:panel ID="_Draggable" CssClass="draggable ui-widget-content" runat="server">
    <p>Drag me to my target</p>
</asp:panel>
<juice:draggable TargetControlID="_Draggable" runat="server"/>

<asp:panel ID="_Default" CssClass="droppable ui-widget-header" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
    <p>Drop here</p>
</asp:panel>
<juice:droppable TargetControlID="_Default" runat="server"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

The document you're reviewing is a partial document. I believe it assumes you have the rest of the document already authored:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Droppable Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Your Code Here -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, I think you are right. It would be nice if the example was more complete

Comment: @RandyGamage They're likely trying to keep the *noise* down in the examples, and present only the functional, relevant, code. Please let me know if this solves your problem.

Comment: "Functional" being the key word!  Too bad it's *not* a functional example!  Even their own demo website, if you look at the source behind the example page, has type attributes for those tags.  Silly not to include them in the example, if you ask me.

Comment: @RandyGamage Like many sites, only the relevant code examples are given. For instance, on jQuery.com you will find examples of code that manipulates document elements which themselves aren't included in the example code. It's a fairly standard practice, but I understand how it can be confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, a little research revealed:

1. element always goes inside the  section - duh
2. the type attribute for  always needs to be type="text/css",
   so I added that
3. Added the type attribute for the  (type="text/javascript")
4. Another error popped up, conflict with the _Default id in the
   example, same as the Default class name when you create a new web
   application.  Bad choice of element ID for an example in which the
   user will likely be doing exactly what I was doing, creating a
   default web app and pasting in the code and expecting it to run.

Don't know why none of these errors were caught when this example was written, but kind of frustrating first experience with Juice UI.  Thanks all for your time and responses.

Comment: The `type` attributes aren't required for `<style>` and `<script>` when you have a standards doctype.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "standards" doctype - I found there are many doctypes, but none called "standards".  My doctype is XHTML 1.0 Transitional.

Comment: There is a specification for how HTML and XHTML should be implemented and parsed. If you were to use `<!DOCTYPE html>` as your doctype, this would put you into standards mode. Within standards mode, you don't need `type` attributes on `<style>` - the browser assumes it's CSS. As is the case with `<script>` - the browser will assume JavaScript. You can still put in the `type` attribute if you like though.

Comment: It sounds like Visual Studio is setup to throw 'validation' warnings as errors, or the author is mistaking warnings for errors. Either way, the environment should be setup to validate against HTML5 and not XHTML 1.0. I'd recommend that for all future projects as well.

I'd also highly recommend going through some beginner HTML tutorials and/or online courses as there's a disconnect here with beginner level aspects of HTML.

Comment: Respectfully, I disagree with the 4th point. Changing a control ID to match the development needs on a particular page is a basic ASP.NET skill. The project assumes that the developer has basic ASP.NET knowledge and has used WebControls in some capacity previously. If a developer is new to ASP.NET and WebControl use, they should first become comfortable with ASP.NET and WebControls before using a 3rd party library. The same holds true for any 3rd party add-on for ASP.NET.

Comment: @shellscape - I think you are confusing my skills (or lack thereof) with my point of making things simple.  I have 15 years of VS development experience, very comfortable changing control IDs, not a problem.  My point is that for an example meant specifically as a "hello world" example for VS/.NET, wouldn't you want to at least be aware of the fact that any new Web Application in VS will set the form name to "Default", so that might not be the best choice for a button name, since it would conflict?  For such an easy-to-avoid stumbling block, it seems silly not to fix this.  Same with XHTML.